# Visual Studio 2015 Community command line build C++ project does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I just upgraded VS2015 ultimate (expired) to community. I have been using the build tools under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC` to build my VC application. After upgrading, the build breaks because

> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h(78)`: **fatal error** C1083: Cannot open include file: `new.h`: No such file or directory

Ultimate has `VC\include\new.h` but Community does not. Is this by design? How can I fix this build break?

Thanks for any clue.

Answer (score 3):

Really simple: create VC\include\new.h with just one line

`#include <new>`

Update: with the release of VS2015 final this above is no longer needed.

That's it.

For the remaining includes add `$(UniversalCRT_IncludePath)` into `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` in project.

Comment: Good finding. Where should this line be added into? stdafx.h? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I added new.h with #include <new> as content. It solved the new.h missing issue. But there come issues related to other header files missing. Trying to fix them using the same solution as new.h does not work. I am wondering if Microsoft plan to fix this so that the customers do not need to hack to fix.

Comment: For a pretty large project this was the only header fix that was needed. Others were solved by adjusting include paths properly. If you can be more specific about which includes were missing and provide exact error message I might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks Berkus. The next error is:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory [C:\jni\jni.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\jni\jni.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Interesting thing is the debug build succeeded but the release build failed due to above error. Both uses "vcvarsall.bat amd64_x86". How to fix this one if it is not the same as new.h?

Comment: I actually tried adding corecrt.h with content of "#include <corecrt>" and confirmed that it is not fixed as new.h. The error of doing this is:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory [C:\jni\jni.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\jni\jni.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Comment: This is answered here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/86bc577b-528c-469c-a506-15383a44c111/missing-corecrth-from-the-default-include-folder-for-vs215?forum=vcgeneral You have to add universal CRT include directory to your include dirs path for project. That's usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10069.0\ucrt` or similar version after Include.

Comment: Adding $(UniversalCRT_IncludePath) into <AdditionalIncludeDirectories> does make the project compile. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Add `$(UniversalCRT_IncludePath)` to `IncludePath`.

Check out what to add to LibraryPath:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by installing the package "Windows Universal CRT SDK" in the VisualStudio Installer.

I'm using the VS2017 Build Tools though.